# Find the functions $f$ that satisfy the given initial value problems

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

> (a) $f'(x)+3x-2=0$, $f(2)=0$
>
> (b) $2f'(x)-\sqrt{x^3} = 0$, $f(0) = 3$

I know the functions need to be integrated to find $f(x)$, however I am unsure as to how to integrate $f'(x)$ in the equation, or whether to consider it when integrating., e.g., for (a) should I integrate $3x-2$ or $f'(x)+3x-2$?

Any idea? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first problem, we have $f'(x)=-3x+2$. Now integrate. We get $f(x)=-\frac{3}{2}x^2+2x+C$ for some $C$. Use the condition $f(2)=0$ to evaluate $C$. If you want to, however, you could integrate immediately, getting from $f'(x)+3x-2=0$ the result $f'(x)+\frac{3}{2}x^2-2x=C$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x)=\int_a^xf'(x)dx+f(a)$$
For $(a)$, $f'(x)=-3x+2$, for $(b)$, $f'(x)=x^{3/2}/2$ Hence
$$(a)~~f(x)=\int_{2}^x(-3x+2)dx+f(2)$$
$$(b)~~f(x)=\int_{0}^xx^{3/2}/2dx+f(0)$$

Answer (score 0):

For equation (a):
$$
f'(x) + 3x -2 = 0 \quad \text{and}\ \ \ f(2) = 0
$$
Solve for $f'(x)$ and rewrite $f'$ as $\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and then integrate:
$$
\mathrm{d}f = (2-3x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
Then integrate:
$$
f = \int (2-3x)\mathrm{d}x = 2x - \frac{3}{2}x^2 + C
$$
And, the condition that $f(2)=0$ allows us to compute the value of C:
$$
f(2) = 2(2) - \frac{3}{2}(2)^2 + C = 0
$$
Yielding a value of $C=2$ unless I have done some arithmetic mistake.